# Why doesn't System Monitor show activity over ethernet connections?

Tags: networking, ethernet, atheros, network-monitoring

In the Network history graph of System Monitor, network activity over Wi-Fi shows up fine, but activity over wired ethernet doesn't show up at all.  Using `lspci`, my ethernet adapter shows up as follows:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Is there any way to fix this?  To be absolutely clear, I am having no problems with the network connection itself, I just am unable to monitor its activity.

Comment: Same issue with my asus N76V with exact pci adapter except older revision : 04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08) Network monitor from Docky is not working either. netwotk activity is working fine as well although.

Comment: @Andrew Did my answer help to solve the issue?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, I just tested using the 3.14.1-trusty kernel, and that fixed the issue.  Sorry it took so long to get back to you on this. I've been a bit busy lately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar ethernet controller and have the same issue:

```
$ lspci | grep Ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

This is a bug that affects Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14.04. The bug has been fixed in Linux Mainline Kernel v3.14 and later. So, you would need to install the mainline kernel to fix the issue.

Download the latest stable release of Mainline Build [from this page](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D). If the folder name doesn't contain the word `rc` in it, then it's a stable build. As of this writing the stable build is [v3.14.1-trusty](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/) (this would work for Ubuntu 13.10 as well).

Download the *.deb files based on your architecture. Refer [this section on Ubuntu Wiki on what you need to download](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds#Installing_upstream_kernels). Once downloaded, open your terminal, `cd` to the downloaded directory and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install them. Then reboot to check if it works for you.

**Note:** You won't get automatic updates for this version of kernel. You would need to manually check the download page and install them yourself to remain updated.

---

- [Refer Ubuntu Wiki on Kernel Mainline Builds for more information about them](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds)
- Following are the bugs reported on Launchpad in this respect; go and mark that you are also affected by the bug:

  1. [Network History no longer works in System Monitor on 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1241894)
  2. [Missing statistics for `tx_bytes`, `tx_packets`, `rx_bytes` and `rx_packets` since Ubuntu 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1292509)

Comment: While installing the 3.14 kernel did fix the issues, I had some issues with dkms modules failing to build when I installed it, so I'll be sticking with using the 3.13 kernel that Ubuntu 14.04 comes with for now.

Comment: @billybadass Make sure to mark those bugs on Lauchpad to state that you are affected by the issue, for it to gather more attention.