# The network speed of System Monitor cannot be shown in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking

I found the *speed value of network monitor* in **System Monitor** cannot be shown after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. Including **indicator-multiload** and **dstat**

#### Example 1:

I can see the download speed is `467KB/Sec` in **firefox Downloads**, but nothing shows (zero) in **Network History**
[image: firefox downloading]

#### Example 2:

In the following image, git downloading speed is `358KB/Sec`, but the receive/send value in `dstat` is still 0.  And nothing shows in `indicator-multiload`

[image: git download]

> **I can get that, the network speed monitor is *disabled* somehow. How can I make it right?**

---

#### Some more information on my network interface

```
┌─ (marslo@MJ ~) ->
└─ $ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:68:84:56  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ef9:ddff:fe68:8456/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:41285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:456734429 (456.7 MB)  TX bytes:456734429 (456.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c2:c6:0a:14:05  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

#### The information of PCI

```
┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ $ lspci | grep Ethernet
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)

┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ $ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Comment: whats your network interface ?

Comment: Hi @raaz, how can I check my network interface?

Comment: by using ifconfig -a

Comment: Hi @raaz, The network interface has been added in my question. Please check it.

Comment: Interesting your traffic forwarding to lo which usually dont get monitored and traffic statistics are bit fishy. May I see your iptable rules ?

Comment: What's the output of `lspci | grep Ethernet`? If it's Qualcomm Atheros AR8161/AR8162, then [see this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409007/why-doesnt-system-monitor-show-activity-over-ethernet-connections).

Comment: Sorry for reply late. I've re-installed my system to Win7 for some other reasons. I'll leave the result after the system re-installed back to ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: However, one thing I can make sure is, **The network speed of System Monitor** works fine while using **wireless network**.

Comment: And my computer is **Dell Vostro 5560**. The **the network speed of System Monitor** works fine in **Ubuntu 13.10**.

Comment: Bug in kernel, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/409007/why-doesnt-system-monitor-show-activity-over-ethernet-connections.

Comment: Hi @Aditya, as your assumption. the PCI is **Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet**. And I've fixed this issue by updated kernel to v3.14.1.

Comment: @Marslo Great... as mentioned in that answer, you would need to check for updates to that kernel yourself to remain updated. Right now the latest kernel in 3.14 series is v3.14.12.

Comment: Hi @Aditya, thanks for you reply. The monitor works after the kernel updated to 3.14.1. :). You can check [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/497490/240267). By the way, I found the latest version for Trusty is [3.15-rc2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc2-trusty/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aditya and @Bryan [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409007/why-doesnt-system-monitor-show-activity-over-ethernet-connections/452168#452168), this is the bug in kernel, and it can be fixed by update kernel.

For example:
My system is `Ubuntu 14.04`. The version of kernel is `3.13.0`, and the system is `64bit (amd64)`.

They all can be got by commands as blew:

```
┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ $ uname -r
3.13.0-30-generic
```

OR

```
┌─ (marslo@MarsloJiao ~) ->
└─ $ dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-"
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-24                               3.13.0-24.47                                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0                                                                          
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic                       3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                                    
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-30                               3.13.0-30.55                                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic                       3.13.0-30.55                                        amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                 3.13.0.30.36                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic                         3.13.0-30.55                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                   3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic                   3.13.0-30.55                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.30.36                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                                  3.13.0-30.55                                        amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-sound-base                                      1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4                                all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
```

---

So, the following steps can fix the problem:

1. there are **three** deb packages should be downloaded from [/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/) first:

   - **linux-headers-.*_amd64.deb** ([linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb))
   - **linux-headers-.*all.deb** ([linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb))
   - **linux-image-.*amd64.deb** ([linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb))
2. Install all these debs

   - `$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
3. Reboot your system

   - `$ sudo reboot`

---

Bingo! The network speed back to the system monitor!!
[image: systemmonitor]

Comment: Excellent work.  This fix carried over to both 16.04 LTS and 17.10 also.  Hopefully it won't crop up again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the network monitor is functioning perfectly: your eth0 and wlan0 devices show 0 bytes sent and 0 bytes received.

Assuming that you actually have some kind of functioning network other that `lo`, you need to find it. I'd start looking here:

1. /proc/net/dev: is this consistent with the ifconfig output?
2. /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net-rules: will show the device names & MACs.
3. dmesg: pipe the output into less or to a file, then search for network device initialization.
4. var/log/syslog: Look for errors of any kind, especially "can't write" or "locked".

My conjecture is that the system can't record any stats because the root file system is read-only, because of a missing device file, or bad permissions.