# Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 No network traffic is shown

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet, atheros

I just bought a new Lenovo Ideapad S410p with this ethernet card:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0200
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
```

Both wireless and eth0 works fine, connect to internet and router no issues there.

But with any tool I used to check the traffic on it shows me zero in both up/down traffic. And this happens ONLY with the ETH0 interface, with the wireles card (another Qualcom Atheros) the traffic is showed, I searched in google with no luck, any idea about how to fix it?

Using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? If you uncheck enable wireless in network manager can you still connect to the internet with your wired connection?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits, both cards works fine at this time. But only the eth0 dont show me traffic in any tool for it. Yes I can connect to the internet with both

Answer (score 0):

After a few days searching I can see my problem is a kernel problem in ubuntu and an old drive version for my ethernet card, like is showed here:

[Answer 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409007/why-doesnt-system-monitor-show-activity-over-ethernet-connections?rq=1)

and confirmed in Launchpad:
[L1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1292509) and 
[L2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1241894)